# Executing non AX report from ax

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, axapta, ax, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement of calling SSRS report that I have developed out of AX , now I need to execute that report from AX with parameters. So is there any possibility to Implement this through AX ? I already called the report through AX but i am not able to pass paramters and excute report on button click. Kindly help me if any one have idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by passing parameters through URL.